# What do the good/evil sliders do in DeathSpank?

Tags: deathspank

DeathSpank's settings have Good/Evil sliders.

Does tweaking them change anything? Are they just a joke?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Move good all the way to the right, and evil all the way to the left to get the "Menu Hero" trophy. Other than that, they are just a joke.

Answer (score 8):

If you slide the "Good" slider all the way up and the "Evil" slider all the way down, you will unlock the "Menu Hero" achievement / trophy.  Beyond that, I haven't noticed any effect on the game.

I strongly suspect these sliders are simply meant make players go "Huh?" :)

Answer (score 3):

When I slid them around,I noticed the UI and the color of everything that wasnt the game itself change,for example,the menu,if slid all the way to Evil,was all red and the sky was a darker color. If slid all the way to Good,it becomes day and bluish.

Answer (score 1):

They are apparently an in-joke of sorts. probably poking fun at all the morality things in games or something my philosophical. I mean how does one judge good and evil? :p

as far as gameplay goes, they're there simply to give you an achievement.