# What do the "Good" and "Evil" sliders do?

Tags: deathspank

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the good/evil sliders do in DeathSpank?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3492/what-do-the-good-evil-sliders-do-in-deathspank)

In the Game Settings I can find those two sliders but I have no clue of their effect (if any) in the game.

Are they just for the show, a joke if you prefer, or they affect the game somehow?